# How to take value from one column and store it in newly created column using function call

Tags: r

firstly sorry if this is a stupid question ... I am learning R, and really dont have too much experience

I have following function in R programming language, that is taking value and returning value.

```
dec2binSingle <- function(decimal) {
print(decimal)
binaryValue <- ""
index <- 0
decimal <- as.numeric(decimal)
while(decimal != 0) {
print(decimal)
    temp <- as.numeric(decimal) %% 2
    if (temp == 1) {
        binaryValue <- paste("1", binaryValue, sep="", collapse = NULL)
        decimal <- decimal - 1
    } else {
        binaryValue <- paste("0", binaryValue, sep="", collapse = NULL)
    }
    index <- index + 1
    decimal <- decimal / 2
}
return(binaryValue)
}
```

The function is converting decimal number into binary equivalent.

When I try to call the function, the function completes without any error, but when I try to see the data, the following error appears:

```
Error in View : 'names' attribute [200] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

And this is the way, how the function is being called:

```
test_function <- function(value1) {return(dec2binSingle(as.numeric(unlist(value1))))}


data_example$tv <- with(data_example, test_function(data_example[which(colnames(data_example) == "numbers")]))
```

Any help is appreciated... thanks

EDIT:

I called the function for single value and it works as expected.

```
> dec2binSingle(23)
[1] "10111"
>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this function doesn't do what you think it does. Could you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @ChiPak I have added the sample of function being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve with your code.

```
#sample data
df <- data.frame(char1=c("abc","def","xyz"), num1=c(1,34,12), num2=c(34,20,8))
df

#function to convert decimal into binary
bin_func <- function(x) {gsub("^0+","",paste(rev(as.numeric(intToBits(x))), collapse=""))}

#verify which all columns are numeric
num_col <- sapply(df,is.numeric)
df1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[,num_col], FUN = function(x) {sapply(x, FUN = bin_func)}))
names(df1) <- paste(names(df1),"_converted",sep="")

#final dataframe having original as well as converted columns
df <- cbind(df,df1)
df
```

*Please don't forget to let us know if it helped :)*

Comment: This is what I wanted to do using the script ... thanks